# Pear coding standards doubts

Tags: php, coding-style, pear

Following [Pear Coding Standards](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.php):

- Should I use `_` before private methods or just for private properties?
- Should I use `methodName` or `method_name` for methods?
- Should I use `public $fooBar` or `public $foo_bar`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Should I use `_` before private methods or just for private properties?

Use `_` before all private member names. This includes properties *and* methods.

> Should I use `methodName` or `method_name` for methods?

Use camel case (that means `methodName`).

> Should I use "public $fooBar" or "public $foo_bar" ?

Separate words with underscores (that means `$foo_bar`).

Some of these are mentioned in the *Class Variables and Methods* section of the [PEAR naming conventions](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.naming.php) document.

Comment: I've made a new question. Thank you very much!

Comment: @thom: You're welcome! To mark an answer as accepted click the hollow checkmark at the left (you may have to wait a few minutes more). Welcome to the site!

Comment: Ok, I need to wait 3 minutes to accept. Can you look at my new question? Thank you.

Comment: @thom: I think it's the same answer as the second one.

Comment: The Pear Coding Standards manual doesn't talk about it. Thank you very much.

Comment: I've read some Pear packages code and they use "public $foo_bar" and "private $_foo_bar" and the methods are like you said. Thank you.